# HP Printer driver installation

Tags: windows-7, drivers, laser-printer, hp-laserjet, print-drivers

Im trying to install a HP LaserJet 100 colorMFP M175a in a Windows 7 x64 notebook thru USB.

Im doing the following steps:

Start the HP printer installation software, basic version

Wait until it asks to plug the printer, then plug the printer.

Then Windows recognizes the printer as a HP LaserJet 100 colorMFP M175a and starts to look for a driver thru Windows Update and then thru local driver store, but it fails.

I tried installing the drivers manually thru the Device Manager, selecting the device named HP LaserJet 100 colorMFP M175a, Update driver, pointing it to the driver folder and selecting the proper driver, but it gives warnings saying that Windows cant verify that the driver works with the device, and the installation fails.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be due to Windows "Driver Signature Enforcement" with the fact you have Windows 7 x64.

You have two options:

1. Find a signed Windows 7 x64 version of your device driver so that it can be installed with driver signature enforcement enabled

OR

2. Disable Driver Signature Enforcement